# Is this mysql transaction code redundant?

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following code that is using `MySQLdb` for db inserts

```
self.cursor.execute('START TRANSACTION;')
for item in data:
    self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO...')

self.cursor.execute('COMMIT;')
self.conn.commit()
```

Is the `self.conn.commit()` at the end redundant, or does that need to be there?

Comment: No, since if one of the inserts results in an integrity error, all will be "rolled back".

Answer (score -1):

If you start a transaction you're responsible for calling `COMMIT` or it'll get unrolled when you close the connection.

As a note it's bad form to include `;` in your queries unless you're using an interactive shell. They're not necessary and immediately raise a bunch of questions about how they came to be included there.

The `;` delimiter is used by the shell to determine where one command stops and the next starts, something that's not necessary when using code where each statement is supplied as a separate string.

Comment: Does this answer the question? Question is asking `self.conn.commit()` which is a Python function. In my opinion, it is redundant.

Comment: @Sraw Whenever possible use the function `commit()` in preference to some raw `COMMIT` call.